# Nintex workflow: Select List in 'Update Item' action dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I am developing a Nintex workflow to find delayed list items(due date <= today) from multiple lists and mail them to concerned user. Each list has a column "NumberOfEscalationMails" which keeps the count of how many reminder mails have been sent. I get the delayed items using ListId variable in 'Query List'. Everything in my workflow works fine till sending mail. But the problem is after sending mail I need to increment the value in column "NumberOfEscalationMails" for each delayed item. But in 'Update Item' action there is no provision to get the list in which I have to update on basis of "List ID". It only provides a dropdown with list name. But I have to choose list dynamically.So I am stuck here at last step! My workflow logic is as follows (Simplified to portions relevant to this question) :

```
-- QueryList to get all the listNames and ListIds from a configuration list and store them in WF collection variables.
-- Foreach loop to iterate through each of above lists.
   -- QueryList Caml query using List ID variable to get all delayed items and store their IDs and Titles in collection variables.
   -- Nested Foreach Loop to iterate through all the delayed items found above.
      -- Build the Item URL and mail them to user.
      -- Increment the column "NumberOfEscalationMails" value.(My Problem.)
--End
```

What should be my approach now?

Answer (score -1):

What about a loop with lists web service?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx